# How Can I Make Text Appear Directly Under Images Organized In A 2x2 Grid?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get text to appear directly under each image organized in a 2x2 grid. I can't seem to get it. I understand writing the p tag right under the images doesn't translate into it's position on the webpage, so I am assuming that it has something to do with the display or position, but I have tried many different iterations and none of them seem to help. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```css
``

.main {
  font-family: fantasy;
  color: white;
}

.main .browse {
  background-color: wheat;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.main img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.row-1 {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
    <section class="main">
        <h2 class="browse">Browse</h2>
        <div class="row-1">
            <img src="./images/macaroon.jpg">
            <p>Category 1</p>
            <img  src="./images/macaroon.jpg">
            <p>Category 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row-2">
            <img src="./images/macaroon.jpg">
            <p>Category 3</p>
            <img src="./images/macaroon.jpg">
            <p>Category 4</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `width: fit-content;` on all `p` tags.

```css
``

.main {
  font-family: fantasy;
  color: white;
}

.main .browse {
  background-color: wheat;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.main img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background-color: pink;
}
.main p{
  width:fit-content;
}
.row-1 {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
        <h2 class="browse">Browse</h2>
        <div class="row-1">
            <img src="./images/macaroon.jpg">
            <p>Category 1</p>
            <img  src="./images/macaroon.jpg">
            <p>Category 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row-2">
            <img src="./images/macaroon.jpg">
            <p>Category 3</p>
            <img src="./images/macaroon.jpg">
            <p>Category 4</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Okay, that allowed the first two p tags to fall under the first two-- except now it changed the layout of the images and they are displayed in a single column.

Answer (score 0):

The correct html element to use here is the `figure` element - which has the img and a `figcaption` element (taht can be the first or the last child of the figure element and can be styled as desired.

The figcaption text can be styled and is semanticlly linked to the img so that it has more meaning as well as being stylistically linked to the img element.

```css
.main {
  font-family: fantasy;
  color: white;
}

.browse {
  background-color: wheat;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.row {
display: flex;
width: 100%;
}

figure {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  text-align: center
}

figcaption {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.row-1 {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
        <h2 class="browse">Browse</h2>
        <div class="row row-1">
          <figure>
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3e/6b/cd/3e6bcdc46881f5355163f9783c44a985.jpg" width="150">
            <figcaption>Category 1</figcaption>
          </figure>
         <figure>
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3e/6b/cd/3e6bcdc46881f5355163f9783c44a985.jpg" width="150">
            <figcaption>Category 2</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-2">
          <figure>
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3e/6b/cd/3e6bcdc46881f5355163f9783c44a985.jpg"width="150">
            <figcaption>Category 3</figcaption>
          </figure>
         <figure>
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3e/6b/cd/3e6bcdc46881f5355163f9783c44a985.jpg"width="150">
            <figcaption>Category 4</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
    </section>
```